# Highcharts: change legend symbol runtime

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Having a 'scatter' chart with custom marker/icon:

```
series: [{
     marker: {
         symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
    }
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sy6nb7fk

Is there any way to replace legend icon when data series is deselected?

i.e. use 'sun_disabled.png'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do a `update` call to change the marker on certain events.

You could do this in `plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick` if the series is shown/hidden using the legend item only. For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sy6nb7fk/1/)):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function(event) {
                var imageName = (this.visible ? 'snow' : 'sun');

                this.update({ 
                    marker: { 
                        symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/'+ imageName +'.png)' 
                    } 
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the series may be shown/hidden using `hide()` and `show()` function calls you could do the same using `Series.events.hide` and `Series.events.show`. For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sy6nb7fk/2/)):

```
series: [{
    events: {
        hide: function() {
            this.update({ 
                marker: { 
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)' 
                } 
            });
        },
        show: function() {
           this.update({ 
                marker: { 
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)' 
                } 
            });
        }
    },
    marker: {
        symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
    },
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
}]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.